# Помогите создать REST заглушку на JAVA в NetBeans

Tags: java, rest, netbeans

Задание:
Необходимо создать REST заглушку в NetBeans.
При переводах система обращается к внешней системе:
REST processing
Принимает POST {"amount":100.0,"rqUID":"fbrebethth","fromAcc":"1111111111111111","toAcc":"2222222222222222"}
Отвечает  {"rqUID":"fbrebethth","statusCode":1}
Система добавляет к прописанному в конфиге пути к заглушке /process/sendTransfer

Из того, что уже есть у меня:

```
package com.mycompany.reststub;

import static com.sun.corba.se.spi.presentation.rmi.StubAdapter.request;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("restStub")
public class RestStub {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    
    public RestStub() {
    }

  
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/process/sendTransfer")

    public String getJson() {
        System.out.println ("GET");
        return "Test Response";
    }
    
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/process/sendTransfer")

    }
    

}
```

Comment: Куда вы собираетесь это деплоить?

Comment: это домашнее задание, не до конца понимаю, как дописать код с "принимает"\"отвечает"